# "System.InvalidCastException" in Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2017

I have a simple `WPF app` where I have included the `QtSharp` (https://github.com/ddobrev/QtSharp) library.

The problem is that my `VisualStudio 2017 v15.5.7` is crashing whenever it tries to load the `QtSharp` `DLLs` for it's `intelliSense`. Somebody know how to prevent crashing or ignoring f.e. a `System.InvalidCastException`? I have already stoppped `ReSharper` to exlude this. The following `Screenshot` and `StackTrace` is shown when I inject a `debugger`.

It's a very strange behavior because on some `methods` or `overloads` it's working like a charm without any problems and after some minutes or (for example) if using the `AddWidget()` `method` it crashes.

### Screenshots

[image: liveCrash]

[image: crash]

[image: Screenshot]

### StackTrace

```
   bei Roslyn.Utilities.EnumUtilities.ConvertEnumUnderlyingTypeToUInt64(Object value, SpecialType specialType)
   bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SymbolDisplay.AbstractSymbolDisplayVisitor.AddNonFlagsEnumConstantValue(INamedTypeSymbol enumType, Object constantValue)
   bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SymbolDisplay.AbstractSymbolDisplayVisitor.AddEnumConstantValue(INamedTypeSymbol enumType, Object constantValue, Boolean preferNumericValueOrExpandedFlags)
   bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SymbolDisplay.AbstractSymbolDisplayVisitor.AddNonNullConstantValue(ITypeSymbol type, Object constantValue, Boolean preferNumericValueOrExpandedFlagsForEnum)
   bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SymbolDisplayVisitor.AddConstantValue(ITypeSymbol type, Object constantValue, Boolean preferNumericValueOrExpandedFlagsForEnum)
   bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SymbolDisplayVisitor.VisitParameter(IParameterSymbol symbol)
   bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Symbols.ParameterSymbol.Accept(SymbolVisitor visitor)
   bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SymbolDisplay.ToDisplayParts(ISymbol symbol, SemanticModel semanticModelOpt, Int32 positionOpt, SymbolDisplayFormat format, Boolean minimal)
   bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SymbolDisplay.ToMinimalDisplayParts(ISymbol symbol, SemanticModel semanticModel, Int32 position, SymbolDisplayFormat format)
   bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Symbol.Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ISymbol.ToMinimalDisplayParts(SemanticModel semanticModel, Int32 position, SymbolDisplayFormat format)
   bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SignatureHelp.AbstractCSharpSignatureHelpProvider.Convert(IParameterSymbol parameter, SemanticModel semanticModel, Int32 position, IDocumentationCommentFormattingService formatter, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SignatureHelp.InvocationExpressionSignatureHelpProvider.c__DisplayClass14_0.b__1(IParameterSymbol p)
   bei System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   bei System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   bei System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SignatureHelp.InvocationExpressionSignatureHelpProvider.ConvertMethodGroupMethod(IMethodSymbol method, InvocationExpressionSyntax invocationExpression, SemanticModel semanticModel, ISymbolDisplayService symbolDisplayService, IAnonymousTypeDisplayService anonymousTypeDisplayService, IDocumentationCommentFormattingService documentationCommentFormattingService, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SignatureHelp.InvocationExpressionSignatureHelpProvider.c__DisplayClass11_0.b__7(IMethodSymbol m)
   bei System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   bei System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   bei System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SignatureHelp.InvocationExpressionSignatureHelpProvider.GetMethodGroupItems(InvocationExpressionSyntax invocationExpression, SemanticModel semanticModel, ISymbolDisplayService symbolDisplayService, IAnonymousTypeDisplayService anonymousTypeDisplayService, IDocumentationCommentFormattingService documentationCommentFormattingService, ISymbol within, IEnumerable`1 methodGroup, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SignatureHelp.InvocationExpressionSignatureHelpProvider.d__5.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SignatureHelp.AbstractSignatureHelpProvider.d__14.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.IntelliSense.SignatureHelp.Controller.Session.d__11.MoveNext()
```

### Debug output

```
    Ausnahme ausgelöst: "StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException" in mscorlib.dll
    Ausnahme ausgelöst: "StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException" in mscorlib.dll
    Ausnahme ausgelöst: "System.OperationCanceledException" in mscorlib.dll
    Ausnahme ausgelöst: "System.OperationCanceledException" in mscorlib.dll
    Ausnahme ausgelöst: "System.OperationCanceledException" in mscorlib.dll
    Ausnahme ausgelöst: "System.OperationCanceledException" in mscorlib.dll
    Ausnahme ausgelöst: "System.OperationCanceledException" in mscorlib.dll
    Ausnahme ausgelöst: "System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException" in mscorlib.dll
    Ausnahme ausgelöst: "System.OperationCanceledException" in mscorlib.dll
    Ausnahme ausgelöst: "System.OperationCanceledException" in mscorlib.dll
    Ausnahme ausgelöst: "System.OperationCanceledException" in mscorlib.dll
    Ausnahme ausgelöst: "System.OperationCanceledException" in mscorlib.dll
    Ausnahme ausgelöst: "System.OperationCanceledException" in mscorlib.dll
    Ausnahme ausgelöst: "System.OperationCanceledException" in mscorlib.dll
    Ausnahme ausgelöst: "StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException" in mscorlib.dll
    Ausnahme ausgelöst: "StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException" in mscorlib.dll
    Ausnahme ausgelöst: "System.OperationCanceledException" in mscorlib.dll
    Ausnahme ausgelöst: "System.OperationCanceledException" in mscorlib.dll
    Ausnahme ausgelöst: "System.OperationCanceledException" in mscorlib.dll
    Ausnahme ausgelöst: "System.OperationCanceledException" in mscorlib.dll
    Ausnahme ausgelöst: "System.OperationCanceledException" in mscorlib.dll
    Ausnahme ausgelöst: "System.OperationCanceledException" in mscorlib.dll
    Ausnahme ausgelöst: "System.OperationCanceledException" in mscorlib.dll
    Ausnahme ausgelöst: "System.OperationCanceledException" in mscorlib.dll
    Ausnahme ausgelöst: "System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException" in mscorlib.dll
    Der Thread 0x5518 hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
    "devenv.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Transactions.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_de_b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.resources.dll" geladen. Das Modul wurde ohne Symbole erstellt.
    System.Transactions Critical: 0 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/UnhandledUnbehandelte AusnahmeDefaultDomainSystem.InvalidCastException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089Die angegebene Umwandlung ist ungültig.   bei Roslyn.Utilities.EnumUtilities.ConvertEnumUnderlyingTypeToUInt64(Object value, SpecialType specialType)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SymbolDisplay.AbstractSymbolDisplayVisitor.AddNonFlagsEnumConstantValue(INamedTypeSymbol enumType, Object constantValue)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SymbolDisplay.AbstractSymbolDisplayVisitor.AddEnumConstantValue(INamedTypeSymbol enumType, Object constantValue, Boolean preferNumericValueOrExpandedFlags)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SymbolDisplay.AbstractSymbolDisplayVisitor.AddNonNullConstantValue(ITypeSymbol type, Object constantValue, Boolean preferNumericValueOrExpandedFlagsForEnum)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SymbolDisplayVisitor.AddConstantValue(ITypeSymbol type, Object constantValue, Boolean preferNumericValueOrExpandedFlagsForEnum)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SymbolDisplayVisitor.VisitParameter(IParameterSymbol symbol)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Symbols.ParameterSymbol.Accept(SymbolVisitor visitor)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SymbolDisplay.ToDisplayParts(ISymbol symbol, SemanticModel semanticModelOpt, Int32 positionOpt, SymbolDisplayFormat format, Boolean minimal)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SymbolDisplay.ToMinimalDisplayParts(ISymbol symbol, SemanticModel semanticModel, Int32 position, SymbolDisplayFormat format)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Symbol.Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ISymbol.ToMinimalDisplayParts(SemanticModel semanticModel, Int32 position, SymbolDisplayFormat format)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SignatureHelp.AbstractCSharpSignatureHelpProvider.Convert(IParameterSymbol parameter, SemanticModel semanticModel, Int32 position, IDocumentationCommentFormattingService formatter, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SignatureHelp.InvocationExpressionSignatureHelpProvider.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass14_0.&lt;ConvertMethodGroupMethod&gt;b__1(IParameterSymbol p)
       bei System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
       bei System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       bei System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SignatureHelp.InvocationExpressionSignatureHelpProvider.ConvertMethodGroupMethod(IMethodSymbol method, InvocationExpressionSyntax invocationExpression, SemanticModel semanticModel, ISymbolDisplayService symbolDisplayService, IAnonymousTypeDisplayService anonymousTypeDisplayService, IDocumentationCommentFormattingService documentationCommentFormattingService, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SignatureHelp.InvocationExpressionSignatureHelpProvider.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass11_0.&lt;GetMethodGroupItems&gt;b__7(IMethodSymbol m)
       bei System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
       bei System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       bei System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SignatureHelp.InvocationExpressionSignatureHelpProvider.GetMethodGroupItems(InvocationExpressionSyntax invocationExpression, SemanticModel semanticModel, ISymbolDisplayService symbolDisplayService, IAnonymousTypeDisplayService anonymousTypeDisplayService, IDocumentationCommentFormattingService documentationCommentFormattingService, ISymbol within, IEnumerable`1 methodGroup, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SignatureHelp.InvocationExpressionSignatureHelpProvider.&lt;GetItemsWorkerAsync&gt;d__5.MoveNext()
    --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
       bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SignatureHelp.AbstractSignatureHelpProvider.&lt;GetItemsAsync&gt;d__14.MoveNext()
    --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
       bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.IntelliSense.SignatureHelp.Controller.Session.&lt;ComputeItemsAsync&gt;d__11.MoveNext()System.InvalidCastException: Die angegebene Umwandlung ist ungültig.
       bei Roslyn.Utilities.EnumUtilities.ConvertEnumUnderlyingTypeToUInt64(Object value, SpecialType specialType)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SymbolDisplay.AbstractSymbolDisplayVisitor.AddNonFlagsEnumConstantValue(INamedTypeSymbol enumType, Object constantValue)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SymbolDisplay.AbstractSymbolDisplayVisitor.AddEnumConstantValue(INamedTypeSymbol enumType, Object constantValue, Boolean preferNumericValueOrExpandedFlags)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SymbolDisplay.AbstractSymbolDisplayVisitor.AddNonNullConstantValue(ITypeSymbol type, Object constantValue, Boolean preferNumericValueOrExpandedFlagsForEnum)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SymbolDisplayVisitor.AddConstantValue(ITypeSymbol type, Object constantValue, Boolean preferNumericValueOrExpandedFlagsForEnum)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SymbolDisplayVisitor.VisitParameter(IParameterSymbol symbol)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Symbols.ParameterSymbol.Accept(SymbolVisitor visitor)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SymbolDisplay.ToDisplayParts(ISymbol symbol, SemanticModel semanticModelOpt, Int32 positionOpt, SymbolDisplayFormat format, Boolean minimal)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SymbolDisplay.ToMinimalDisplayParts(ISymbol symbol, SemanticModel semanticModel, Int32 position, SymbolDisplayFormat format)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Symbol.Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ISymbol.ToMinimalDisplayParts(SemanticModel semanticModel, Int32 position, SymbolDisplayFormat format)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SignatureHelp.AbstractCSharpSignatureHelpProvider.Convert(IParameterSymbol parameter, SemanticModel semanticModel, Int32 position, IDocumentationCommentFormattingService formatter, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SignatureHelp.InvocationExpressionSignatureHelpProvider.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass14_0.&lt;ConvertMethodGroupMethod&gt;b__1(IParameterSymbol p)
       bei System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
       bei System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       bei System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SignatureHelp.InvocationExpressionSignatureHelpProvider.ConvertMethodGroupMethod(IMethodSymbol method, InvocationExpressionSyntax invocationExpression, SemanticModel semanticModel, ISymbolDisplayService symbolDisplayService, IAnonymousTypeDisplayService anonymousTypeDisplayService, IDocumentationCommentFormattingService documentationCommentFormattingService, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SignatureHelp.InvocationExpressionSignatureHelpProvider.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass11_0.&lt;GetMethodGroupItems&gt;b__7(IMethodSymbol m)
       bei System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
       bei System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       bei System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SignatureHelp.InvocationExpressionSignatureHelpProvider.GetMethodGroupItems(InvocationExpressionSyntax invocationExpression, SemanticModel semanticModel, ISymbolDisplayService symbolDisplayService, IAnonymousTypeDisplayService anonymousTypeDisplayService, IDocumentationCommentFormattingService documentationCommentFormattingService, ISymbol within, IEnumerable`1 methodGroup, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SignatureHelp.InvocationExpressionSignatureHelpProvider.&lt;GetItemsWorkerAsync&gt;d__5.MoveNext()
    --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
       bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SignatureHelp.AbstractSignatureHelpProvider.&lt;GetItemsAsync&gt;d__14.MoveNext()
    --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
       bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       bei Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.IntelliSense.SignatureHelp.Controller.Session.&lt;ComputeItemsAsync&gt;d__11.MoveNext()
    Ein Ausnahmefehler des Typs "System.InvalidCastException" ist in Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.dll aufgetreten.
    Die angegebene Umwandlung ist ungültig.
```

Comment: _Init need to return QLayout ?

Comment: @LeonBarkan I have added a `gif` where the crash happens.

Comment: seems like vs bug :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of the wrong `Qt version`. I had used **5.10.1** and with **5.9.4** it is working as expected!